# Вывести итоговый статус за каждый день

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица записей с полями `datetime(Int)` и `status(Smallint)`. 
Статус может быть 1 - Успех, 2 - Отказ. Нужно вывести за каждый день, все ли записи успешные, или все отказные, или смешанные.
Конечная таблица должна иметь такой вид:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    | result | 
+------------+--------+
| 27/08/2019 |    1   | 
| 28/08/2019 |    2   | 
| 29/08/2019 |    3   | 
+------------+--------+
```

Не пойму как составить вложенный запрос для определения итогового статуса.
Наработки:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`datetime`), '%e/%m/%Y') AS `date`,
FROM `table1`
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: если min(status)=max(status) то значит в группе статус только один и значит можно однозначно говорить успех/отказ. Если не равны, значит смешанный

Comment: @Mike. Это оказалось проще, чем кажется. Спасибо.